# New feature in .NET Framework?

Tags: c#, .net

I have a research about feature "Data Access Application Block" in EntLib. I find some codes:

```
public static class MapBuilder<TResult> where TResult : new()
{
    //...
}
```

I don't understand about meaning of declaring of this class when using "**where TResult : new()**". I think this is new feature in .NET Framework to declare a class. Please give me a document or link to explain about this feature. Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's a generic type parameter constraint. It's been around since the introduction of generics, in .net 2.0.

[Constraints on Type Parameters (MSDN)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970.aspx)

The particular constraint you've mentioned means only a class with a public parameterless constructor can be used as the type `TResult`.

---

See also: [Generics (MSDN)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/512aeb7t%28v=VS.100%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

`where TResult : new()` adds a [constraint on the generic](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970.aspx) type parameter (`TResult`). The type argument must have a parameterless constructor.